# Using XMLHttpRequest to GET Ecobee API info. Getting a 500 (Error 1: "Authentication failed. Token is required.")

Tags: javascript, ecobee, ecobee-api

The API requires a header that will contain the Authorization code. So this what I have so far:

```
 var fullUrl = 'https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat?json=\{"selection":\{"includeAlerts":"true","selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":"","includeEvents":"true","includeSettings":"true","includeRuntime":"true"\}\}' ;
var nestRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
nestRequest.open("GET", fullUrl, true);
var temp: "AUTHORIZATION_CODE_GOES_HERE";
nestRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + temp);
```

I was able to query with Curl and I know the token is correct. But when I try with XMLHttpRequest I am getting this error:

500:

code:1
message:"Authentication failed. Token is required."

And that leads me to think that something is wrong on setting up the HEADER ...

This is what is required on header:

> HEADERS:
>       Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>       Authorization: Bearer Rc7JE8P7XUgSCPogLOx2VLMfITqQQrjg

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, one thing you're doing wrong is showing your authentication code in plain text...

Comment: Where's the rest of your code, the part where you call `send()` and handle the response? I tried that URL (minus the backslashes, which shouldn't be necessary) and I was told the token expired.

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp: "AUTHORIZATION_CODE_GOES_HERE";
```

This should be:

```
var temp = "AUTHORIZATION_CODE_GOES_HERE";
```